# Is it possible to set a static ip in a Netboot.iso

Tags: centos7

I need to deploy CentOS7 systems without using DHCP. So I was hoping someone would know if its possible to append a static IP in the isolinux.cfg file and create a custom netboot iso.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

I found this addition at can be added to the label in the isolinux.cfg that will configure a static ip.

ip=ip::gateway:netmask:hostname:interface:none